# Binary List to PNG in Python

Tags: python, image-manipulation

Forgive me for any naivety, but I am new to working with images.  Say I have a list of binary values [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0....] which represent pixels in a black and white image.  How would I go about making a .png file from this list?

Comment: Is this just a 1-D list?

Comment: Yes, it's just a 1-D list, but I want to make a 5x5 image and do want to map 0 to pure black and 1 to pure white.  I can't figure out how to work with BasicWolf's suggestion, it creates an image, but the image is all black.

Comment: Actually it's mostly black. If you take his suggestion, you'll be writing 0 and 1, which out of 255 will look pretty darn black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Python Imaging Library for this purpose.

There is a `img = Image.frombuffer(mode, size, data)` method which creates an image from "raw" data (a string). You can then save it as PNG file via `img.save('image.png', transparency=transparency)`

Comment: Yes but he wants to map 0 to pure black (0,0,0) and 1 to pure white (255,255,255)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on BasicWolf's example:

```
from PIL import Image
import struct

size = 5, 5
arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
data = struct.pack('B'*len(arr), *[pixel*255 for pixel in arr])
img = Image.frombuffer('L', size, data)
img.save('image.png')
```

I think this is what you're after...